# how to read both comma separated and pipe line separated csv file in a single item reader in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am new to sprig batch. 
I have a folder which contain multiple csv file, I have implemented MultiResourceItemReader () to read those file . It is working only if all csv file are pipe line  ("|") separated.

I want to read both comma (",") separated csv and pipe line  separated csv using single reader. Is it possible ? if yes how ?

Here is my code

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourceItemReader<Person> multiResourceItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[x]}") String x,@Value("#{jobParameters[y]}") String y,@Value("#{jobParameters[z]}") String z) {

    Resource[] resourcessss = null;
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
    try {
        resourcessss = resolver.getResources("file:" + z);
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
    MultiResourceItemReader<Person> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<Person>();
    resourceItemReader.setResources(resourcessss);
    resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());

    return resourceItemReader;
}



@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[]{"Id","postCode"});
                }
                {
                    setDelimiter("|");
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Person.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer`. There, you can use a `Pattern` to identify what records get parsed by what `LineTokenizer`. In your case, you'd have one `Pattern` that identifies comma delimited records and map them to the tokenizer that parses via commas. You'd also have a `Pattern` that identifies records delimited by pipes and maps those to the appropriate `LineTokenizer`. It would look something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public LineTokenizer compositeLineTokenizer() throws Exception {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer commaTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        commaTokenizer.setNames("a", "b", "c");
        commaTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        commaTokenizer.afterPropertiesSet();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer pipeTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        pipeTokenizer.setNames("a", "b", "c");
        pipeTokenizer.setDelimiter("|");

        pipeTokenizer.afterPropertiesSet();

        // I have not tested the patterns here so they may need to be adjusted
        Map<String, LineTokenizer> tokenizers = new HashMap<>(2);
        tokenizers.put("*,*", commaTokenizer);
        tokenizers.put("*|*", pipeTokenizer);

        PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer();

        lineTokenizer.setTokenizers(tokenizers);

        return lineTokenizer;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Minella . Thank you for your reply. After creating this bean in my BatchConfig class how I will link this into my existing reader() function. What changes do I need to make for existing bean so that your solution will work ?

Comment: public FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> build = new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<FieldSet>().name("fileReader")

                .lineTokenizer(compositeLineTokenizer())
                .build();
                return build;
    }

Comment: Your `FlatFileItemReader` shouldn't return a `FieldSet`...you should map it to something... but otherwise (assuming you'll also add a `Resource`), yes it looks correct.

Comment: Hi @Michael Minella , I am getting Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The LineTokenizer must be set. tried to extends DefaultLineMapper and override setLineTokenizer() but no luck, same error ..

Comment: You also need to configure a `FieldSetMapper`.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael . Just added few more line into my reader to make it work as you suggested,  .fieldSetMapper( new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>())
                .targetType(Person.class)